# Nodejs Native token transaction

Tags: native-assets, javascript

I am looking to build a native token transaction in nodeJS using either Cardanocli-Js or Cardano-wallet js but the documentation is massively lacking can anyone give me an example i can look over to understand what i will need to do.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.